# Validation Errors in SSIS Package when columns are mapped correctly

Tags: sql-server, ssis-2012

I have a SSIS package that I am working on. As soon as I open the SSIS package I am given the following error:

> Validation error. Populate Organisations Table: Organisation Table destination: 'Organisation Table destination' has 2 input columns that are not mapped to upstream columns. Delete the unmapped input columns or map columns to them with the Resolve References editor. For example, one of the unmapped input columns is 'Organisation_OrganisationId_PimsCode'

But when I look at the mappings, the mapping exists, and it is looking fine!

[image: mappings]

Why is this happening? When I Rebuild solution, it builds fine with no errors, but then a minute or so later when I open a Data Flow Task (has red cross next to it) the error show up in the errors window.

Comment: Could You describe which data types has issued columns (both SQL and IS)?

Comment: From what I can see, they are both `VarChar` but one is `VarChar(40)` and one is `VarChar(5)`

Comment: When I double click on the path between tasks, in the Data Flow Editor, the Data Type for both is `DT_STR`

Comment: Which version of SSDT are you using? And have you checked the advanced properties of the source or destination to be sure the source has proper output columns and the destination has matching input columns?